# Could not find or load main class in jar

Tags: java

I have a jar file that contains `META-INF` directory and `.java` class if I am trying to run the `java -cp jarName.jar com.className` I am getting this error `Error: Could not find or load main class SortFile`. Why I am getting this error if I am openning this `.java` I can see that the `package` is just `com` any advice? Also when I am in the same directory of project where is located the `.java` and trying to compile it to a class and then `java compiled.class` the same error appears.

My manifest file contains these lines:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: SortFile
```

and the jar also holds the `SortFile.class` and the `package` is `com` I would like to use this class but when I am trying to write `java -cp SortFile.jar com.SortFile` I am getting the error above.

```
$ jar tf SortFile.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
SortFile.mf
SortFile.class
```

Comment: Runnable Jar files should contain compiled class files, not .java source files.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch even I compiled a class and added it with the Manifest to the jar and after that when I am trying to `java -cp jarFile.jar com.Class` I am still getting this error, why? Is there something wrong? my package of that class is just `com`

Comment: Your manifest.mf file should contain main class with com.place.somename.ClassName something like. If you run simply java -jar someJarFileName.jar, it should run.

Comment: @Reddi Please [edit] your question to include the output of `jar tf jarName.jar`. Also add the content of the files in the `META-INF` directory to your question.

Comment: @Reddi Your class `SortFile` is not in a directory `com/`

Comment: @Progman the file is in `C:/dir/src/main/java/com/SortFile.java` What I am doing wrong? When I do a jar of this class I can not move it from this path? When I am doing javac SortFile.java and going to `C:/dir/src/main/java` and type java com.SortFile then it works but when I am going to this dir and typing just `java SortFile` I am getting error.

Comment: @Reddi The `SortFile.class` file must be inside a directory `com/`, because it belongs to the package `com`. The `.class` files cannot be just on the top level of the jar file. Change the way you create the jar file and place the .class files in the directory matching the packages they are in.

Comment: @Progman it works, but weird is that when I am trying to do `jar cvfm SortFile.jar SortFile.mf -C com/ SortFile.class` it do not take the `com` dir and do not add the class inside this dir I do not know why, but I know that the problem belongs to it, because I added this dir by myself using 7 zip and it works.

Comment: @Reddi Well, you use `-C com/` and that is **exactly** what it is doing. Check the documentation of the `jar` command to see what the `-C` switch is doing.

Answer (score 0):

For enter the Main class, you do enter before her package.

Exemple :

```java
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyMainClass
```

(After, I don't know for the problem in the terminal. Maybe it's because your Main class is not correctly enter.)